# Setting up an offset with anchor tags for a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a single page which has a navbar and with links pointing to section id in the page.

However, when I click on the link the section of the page scrolls down till the top of the section and due to my sticky navbar, the top part of my section goes behind it.

**How do I create an offset height which would match my navbar height so that the div is visible at the right position?**

Here is my a screenshot of what is happening.

[image: Screenshot]

*Also, is there a way to smoothly scroll till the section? What is the easiest method to achieve this?*

My example code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Sction 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="section1">Section 1</div>
<div id="section2">Section 2</div>
<div id="section3">Section 3</div>
```

Comment: `div[id^="section"] {margin-top: 80px; margin-bottom: -80px;}`

Comment: This question can be solved with a little help from google and even less logic, but the efforts put in the answers are definitely because of the signature at the end of the question. *Just saying*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offsetting anchor hash tag links to adjust for fixed header

HTML :

```
<a href="#section1">Goto Section I</a>

<!-- Some more content -->


<h3 id="section1" class="offset">Section I</h3>

<p>Section specific content</p>
```

CSS:

```
.offset:before { 
    display: block; 
    content: " "; 
    height: 150px;      /* Give height of your fixed element */
        margin-top: -150px; /* Give negative margin of your fixed element */    
        visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `padding-top` to that section which is equal to the `header height`. Like if your header has a `height: 40px` then give `padding-top: 40px` to that section.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  background: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sec {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #ff0;
  padding-top: 48px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="section1" class="sec">Section 1</div>
<div id="section2" class="sec">Section 2</div>
<div id="section3" class="sec">Section 3</div>
```

Hope this helps!